# Quickly calculate number of One-way, Two-way links from very large edge list

Tags: r, graph-theory

I have a 4 GB file with around 2 Billion directed edges in the format User1 FOLLOWS User 2, shown below.

```
User1       User2
7           37
5           24
7           8383932
24          1
3           8538
37          7

DF = structure(list(User1 = c(7L, 5L, 7L, 24L, 3L, 37L), User2 = c(37L, 
24L, 8383932L, 1L, 8538L, 7L)), .Names = c("User1", "User2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and so on.  I want to be able to efficiently get the following results

```
User        NumberFollowers        NumberFriends
1           1                      0
7           1                      1
24          1                      0
37          1                      1
8383932     1                      0
8538        1                      0
5           0                      0
3           0                      0
```

and so on, where NumberFollowers is the number of "User1"'s with links to them, and NumberFriends is the number of Follower's they have that they also mutually follow.

I currently tried using

```
aggregate()
```

However it seems to ignore cases like User 5 and User 3 who have no friends or followers, but they themselves follow people.

I'd rather not have to loop through the entire thing, as it will take forever with how many edges I have.

Is there any good, efficient way of doing this relatively quickly and painlessly?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use igraph which is designed for such things.

Comment: Your output looks wrong. 37 has a friend (7).

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that. Can iGraph provide me a list of friends/followers while retaining the unique-User ID so I can cross-reference these to other datasets that I have?

Comment: Yeah, I think it can. I haven't used it enough to know how, though.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

res0 <- rbind(
  DT[, .N, by=.(user=User2)][, lab := "followers"],
  DT[.(User2, User1), on=names(DT), nomatch=0][, .N, by=.(user=User2)][, lab := "friends"]
)[, dcast(.SD, user ~ lab, value.var = "N", fill = 0L)]

      user followers friends
1:       1         1       0
2:       7         1       1
3:      24         1       0
4:      37         1       1
5:    8538         1       0
6: 8383932         1       0
```

This excludes users with no followers, but they're fairly simple to add back if desired.

`DT` itself lists followers; and `DT[.(User2, User1), on=names(DT), nomatch=0]` lists friends.

This is near the limit of what one can sanely do with this data in tabular format. Anything fancier and you will really want a graph. See the igraph package.

---

Assorted notes:

- The syntax `DT[i,j,by]` means subset using `i`; group by `by`; and do `j`. See `?data.table`.
- Tasks can be chained like `DT[...][...]`.
- `:=` is a special symbol for assigning to a column.
- `.N` is a special variable counting the rows in a group. See `?.N`.
- `on=` and `nomatch=` are helper arguments when using `i` for a "join," also in `?data.table`.
- `dcast` is a helper function for reshaping from long to wide format. See `?dcast`.

Comment: Wow, this is actually lightning fast compared to what I was doing. Thanks!

I guess I'll just compare the full list of IDs to the list of ID's with followers, and whoever doesn't appear append with zeroes.

Thanks again.